# Google Translate API Python

Tags: python, google-translate

I'm having some troubles with the Google Translate API.

Example;

When translating the title of this article:

http://vtimes.com.au/dua-xe-f1-thu-ngua-chien-bat-them-benh-2622229.html

(Đua xe F1: Thử "ngựa chiến" bắt thêm bệnh)

The quote marks come back as &quot

When using translate.google.com it obviously come's back as you want it.

Am I missing some encoding or something(?) Gah! Help :D

Code snippet:

```
service = build('translate', 'v2',
                 developerKey=self.config['google-api']['dev-key'])
    try:
        title = (service.translations().list(
            source=source,
            target='en',
            q=text
        ).execute())['translations'][0]['translatedText']
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        return text
    return title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an easy solution to this. The html package saved the day.

```
import html

service = ...
   ...
...

return html.unescape(title)
```